# Is Google app engine the best option for commercial web apps?

Tags: google-app-engine

I wrote a little web app with jsp's and have it working on the localhost using tomcat and a mysql database. I want to put it on the web so that I can view it from anywhere and have thought about using my spare laptp to host it (which I have no idea how to do). I started searching around and read a bit about google app engine. I thought maybe I could figure out how to get my project uploaded through that, but I haven't yet. Anyway, from all I read I am starting to wonder if google app engine really is the best answer. I have some other ideas of web apps I want to create and wonder if using google apps is my best option. If I create the next youtube or pandora.com am I going to have problems because I chose to go with Google App Engine? Should I just go the hard way and try to figure out how to get my (now small) web app onto a third party server or something? And if I should then where should I start looking to figure this stuff out?

Comment: This isn't really a good SO question it is very open ended and subjective. I predict you will get modded down soon.  That being said ultimately you need to understand the strengths and weaknesses of all of the potential platform choices.  Do you want to look after the OS?  If the answer is no then you should look at appengine/heroku style services.  If you want transparent scaling - with no intervention from you except for budget ;-)  then you probably want appengine.  Appengine dependance on the datastore will tend to lock you in.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already developed your app and want minimal effort to get it hosted you might want to try AWS instead - simple, cheap and scalable. If on the other hand your app (particularly your db schema) is simple, then you might prefer to migrate the code to app engine. I would recommend [reading the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview) and [doing some tutorials](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted) to see what's possible, and then making a decision based on your experiences

Comment: I guess that's the big problem. I feel like I need to commit to something but I'm so new to server/hosting technologies that I have no idea what I am doing and can't figure it out fast enough. I'm scared that I am going to develop my app around google and then start having problems because google is somehow limiting my potential but I can't move the app, etc..